# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psycopg

I am trying to use parameterized query with `psycopg` for deleting a bunch of rows. My script has the deletion statement like:

```
cur.executemany( "WITH remove_rows as (DELETE FROM users WHERE userid = %s RETURNING *), insert_rows as (INSERT INTO old.users SELECT * FROM remove_rows RETURNING *) SELECT count(*) from insert_rows;", (id,))
```

And the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "removal.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur.executemany( "WITH remove_rows as (DELETE FROM .users WHERE userid = %s RETURNING *), insert_rows as (INSERT INTO old.users SELECT * FROM remove_rows RETURNING *) SELECT count(*) from insert_rows;", (id,))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: ...ws as (DELETE FROM users WHERE userid = %s RETURNI...
```

When I remove the space from `userid = %s` and made it `userid=%s`, I got same error with message `column "s" does not exist`.

I am starting to wonder if `psycopg2` parameterization does not handle CTEs?

Comment: I focussed on the `cur.executemany()` call, but since I am not familiar with CTEs I am not confident that it'll work even if you were to use `cur.execute()` instead. As such I deleted my answer.

Comment: I realized that after posting. execute() resolved my issue :) thanks

Comment: Okay, undeleted my answer then. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executemany()` takes a *nested set of sequences* of parameters, not one.

Either wrap your parameters into another list, or use `cur.execute()` instead to run the query just once.